# pinject basic use case fails

Tags: python, ioc-container

Tried to use pinject (https://github.com/google/pinject) today for the first time, but for some reason this basic test fails on assert:

```
def test_container():
    from pinject import new_object_graph
    graph = new_object_graph(modules=None, classes=[Repository])
    repo1 = graph.provide(Repository)
    repo2 = graph.provide(Repository)
    assert repo1 is repo2
```

Documentation states that:

> Singleton scope (SINGLETON) is the default and always caches

Comment: okay, gave up on pinject and found lightweight container that uses type annotations with simple interface that just works: https://github.com/meadsteve/lagom

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this library, but I notice in the documentation an example that is similar looking to yours and yet is completely different in terms of what it is expecting the `pinspect` library to do:

```
import pinject

class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        self.foo = foo

class SomeBindingSpec(pinject.BindingSpec):
        def provide_foo(self):
            return object()

obj_graph = pinject.new_object_graph(binding_specs=[SomeBindingSpec()])
some_class_1 = obj_graph.provide(SomeClass)
some_class_2 = obj_graph.provide(SomeClass)
print(some_class_1.foo is some_class_2.foo)
```

This code is not testing if the two objects returned by `obj_graph.provide` are the same object.  Rather, those objects have had an object injected into them as attribute `foo`.  The code is checking to see if the same object has been injected into the two SomeClass objects.

The line that checks for equal objects is telling:

```
some_class_1.foo is some_class_2.foo
```

Not only is this checking that the `foo` attribute of each `some_class` is the same object, it's pretty much telling you that you shouldn't expect `some_class_1` and `some_class_2` to be the same object, or why bother to check to see if their `foo` attributes are the same. If the two outer objects are the same object, then of course any attribute gotten by either reference to that one object would be the same.

So it seems to me that you are misunderstanding how the library works and at what point the notion of a SINGLETON is introduced.

Comment: well, I assumed that it works like any other ioc container, but it seems that what pinject people call 'singleton' lifetime strategy is actually 'per-resolve' one. So it seems to me that authors of this library misunderstand basics of ioc container design principles ;)